# Javascript: link to a specific div in a new page?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

How can I create a link that opens a new page and also scrolls to a specified div in that new page?

Comment: By adding a hash matching an element in the new page.

Answer (score 3):

You don't even need to use Javascript.

```
<a href="http://example.com/page#id_of_div" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

Comment: @var___ - don't worry, this happens all the time, and it's usually not an issue. Answers that are exact copies, added half an hour later etc. just to try and gather a few point. Not a good idea!